# Need to install ngx-boostrap version 4 for ngx-editor

Tags: angular

I have installed the ngx-editor@4.0.0 and  ngx-bootstrap with "npm install ngx-bootstrap --save".  By default it installed version 3 and giving the error.

How can i install the ngx-boostrap version 4, is there any command like npm install ngx-bootstrap@4.0.0

Comment: Why do you need v4 of `ngx-bootstrap`? The latest version is `3.0.1`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, After install the bootstrap using this "npm install ngx-bootstrap", its giving an error " ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module ..node_modules/ngx-editor/ngx-editor.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule "